# Strange behaviour with MongoDB sort operation

Tags: database, mongodb, sorting

Here is the information collection and sample data:

1. Query to get all docs with `eid:abc` and sorted by role.
   `db.information.find({eid:"abc"}).sort({role:1})` giving expected
   result, but when changing `eid:aaa`, result is not coming in sorting
   order, order is random.
2. On contradictory when changing sort object to `role:-1`, its sorting
   output in ascending order but then for `eid:abc` output comes in
   descending order. it's just behaving strangely.

Using MongoDB shell version v4.0.6 :

```
 information =[
      {_id:'110',role:'dev',eid:'aaa',info:["a","b"]},
      {_id:'111',role:'tester',eid:'abc',info:["a","b","c"]},
      {_id:'112',role:'admin',eid:'abc',info:["a","c"]}
      {_id:'113',role:'admin',eid:'abc',info:["a","b","c"]},
      {_id:'114',role:'dev',eid:'abc',info:["a","b","c"]},
      {_id:'115',role:'admin',eid:'aaa',info:["a","b","c"]}
 ];


 Output:

 1.when .find({eid:"aaa"}).sort:{role:1}
 => 
 [          
  {_id:'115',role:'admin',eid:'aaa',info:["a","b","c"]}
  {_id:'110',role:'dev',eid:'aaa',info:["a","b"]},
 ];

 2.when .find({eid:"abc"}).sort:{role:1}
 => [      
     {_id:'111',role:'tester',eid:'abc',info:["a","b","c"]},
     {_id:'114',role:'dev',eid:'abc',info:["a","b","c"]}
     {_id:'112',role:'admin',eid:'abc',info:["a","c"]}
     {_id:'113',role:'admin',eid:'abc',info:["a","b","c"]}];

 3.when .find({eid:"aaa"}).sort:{role:-1}
 => 
 [{_id:'110',role:'dev',eid:'aaa',info:["a","b"]}
 {_id:'115',role:'admin',eid:'aaa',info:["a","b","c"]}]

 4.when .find({eid:"abc"}).sort:{role:-1}
 => 
 [{_id:'113',role:'admin',eid:'abc',info:["a","b","c"]},
 {_id:'112',role:'admin',eid:'abc',info:["a","c"]},
 {_id:'111',role:'tester',eid:'abc',info:["a","b","c"]},
 {_id:'114',role:'dev',eid:'abc',info:["a","b","c"]}]
```

Comment: Update the question will all the responses you got from different queries.

Comment: The syntax should be `.sort({ "role": 1 })` not `.sort:{role: 1}`. Although I think you actually used the correct syntax in the shell.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I got with a similar environment using Mongo Shell. The [sort](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/index.html) works fine for all four cases.

Note that the `find` query filter is on the field `eid` and the `sort` is applied on the field `role`.

```
> db.sorts.find()
{ "_id" : "110", "role" : "dev", "eid" : "aaa", "info" : [ "a", "b" ] }
{ "_id" : "111", "role" : "tester", "eid" : "abc", "info" : [ "a", "b", "c" ] }
{ "_id" : "112", "role" : "admin", "eid" : "abc", "info" : [ "a", "c" ] }
{ "_id" : "113", "role" : "admin", "eid" : "abc", "info" : [ "a", "b", "c" ] }
{ "_id" : "114", "role" : "dev", "eid" : "abc", "info" : [ "a", "b", "c" ] }
{ "_id" : "115", "role" : "admin", "eid" : "aaa", "info" : [ "a", "b", "c" ] }

> db.sorts.find({ eid: "aaa" }).sort({ role: 1 })
{ "_id" : "115", "role" : "admin", "eid" : "aaa", "info" : [ "a", "b", "c" ] }
{ "_id" : "110", "role" : "dev", "eid" : "aaa", "info" : [ "a", "b" ] }

> db.sorts.find({ eid: "abc" }).sort({ role: 1 })
{ "_id" : "112", "role" : "admin", "eid" : "abc", "info" : [ "a", "c" ] }
{ "_id" : "113", "role" : "admin", "eid" : "abc", "info" : [ "a", "b", "c" ] }
{ "_id" : "114", "role" : "dev", "eid" : "abc", "info" : [ "a", "b", "c" ] }
{ "_id" : "111", "role" : "tester", "eid" : "abc", "info" : [ "a", "b", "c" ] }

> db.sorts.find({ eid: "aaa" }).sort({ role: -1 })
{ "_id" : "110", "role" : "dev", "eid" : "aaa", "info" : [ "a", "b" ] }
{ "_id" : "115", "role" : "admin", "eid" : "aaa", "info" : [ "a", "b", "c" ] }

> db.sorts.find({ eid:"abc" }).sort({ role: -1 })
{ "_id" : "111", "role" : "tester", "eid" : "abc", "info" : [ "a", "b", "c" ] }
{ "_id" : "114", "role" : "dev", "eid" : "abc", "info" : [ "a", "b", "c" ] }
{ "_id" : "112", "role" : "admin", "eid" : "abc", "info" : [ "a", "c" ] }
{ "_id" : "113", "role" : "admin", "eid" : "abc", "info" : [ "a", "b", "c" ] }
```